# HTML5 - Canvas: Draw text over gradient

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I want to write some text over a gradient (to make a scale):

I have this so far:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// Create gradient
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,500,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
grd.addColorStop(0.5,"yellow");
grd.addColorStop(1,"green");
// Fill with gradient
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,100);
```

```html
    
    
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

I can't see the text. How can I fix this?

I want to create this:
[image]

Where the circle is generated from some score that I give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

- You're drawing the background overtop of the text
- You're drawing the background and text in the same gradient, so the text will be invisible on top of the background

Move the text-drawing *after* the rectangle, and change its color:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// Create gradient
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,500,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
grd.addColorStop(0.5,"yellow");
grd.addColorStop(1,"green");
// Fill with gradient
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,100);

ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the text last. I can see you are drawing the filled rectangle over the text you have already drawn. Try doing this instead:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// Create gradient
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,500,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
grd.addColorStop(0.5,"yellow");
grd.addColorStop(1,"green");
// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,100);
//write text with canvas methods
c.fillStyle = '#000000';
c.font = "30px Arial";
c.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
</script>
```

You may also want to consider looking up `canvas.textAlign` and `canvas.textBaseline` properties for positioning the text;